# C# task.wait method called not finished

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am trying to get a better understanding of Tasks and Async operations in C# and I have this sample program running but I am confused about the output.  When I run this sometimes the program doesn't output the Console output in CallMethod after

```
int length = await task
```

and sometimes it does but when I uncomment

```
Console.ReadLine()
```

it always runs all of CallMethod.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tasks1
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = new Task(CallMethod);
            task.Start();
            task.Wait();
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }

    static async void CallMethod()
    {
        string filePath = "/Users/testname/Projects/Tasks1/Tasks1/Sample.txt";
        Task<int> task = ReadFile(filePath);

        Console.WriteLine("Other Work 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Other Work 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Other Work 3");

        int length = await task;
        Console.WriteLine(" Total Length: " + length);

        Console.WriteLine("After work 1");
        Console.WriteLine("After work 2");

    }

    static async Task<int> ReadFile(string file)
    {
        int length = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("File reading is starting");

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string s = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            length = s.Length;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File reading is complete");
        return length;
    }


}
}
```

[image: Not finishing CallMethod]
[image: Finishing CallMethod]

Answer (score 7):

`async void` - it is always `async void` :) Basically, don't use `async void` unless you're very aware of why you're using it. The call-path cannot know the completion status of an `async void`, so *from the perspective of the caller* it will run to the first non-synchronous `await`. After that, you're in a thread-race scenario. It cannot participate in the outermost `Wait()` (or `await`), since it doesn't report status. An exe exits when all non-background threads complete, so: sometimes it might work, mostly not. Adding the `Console.ReadLine()` forces it to wait for longer, hence why it works.

Basically: make `CallMethod` return `Task`.

BTW: with recent C# versions, you can make your `Main` method `async` too:

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {...}
```

Then you can `await` in your `Main`. The number of times you should `Wait()` on a task is *almost* zero; usually you should prefer `await`.

Comment: I think async void is supported only because of button click event handler signatures and thats its only useful case as far as I know.

Comment: @CRice I've used it a few cases when I'm starting a background worker and *nobody is listening for the result* - all error handling etc is self-contained in the worker.